# What is the greatest known age difference between Picard and his lovers?

Tags: star-trek, jean-luc-picard

I was just reading [this post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/161042/how-old-was-commander-will-riker-around-s1e1-of-star-trek-tng?rq=1), which told me that Picard was not too young when he had his relationships with some young women (Vash in "Captain's Holiday" or Anij in *Insurrection,* for example).

Even recently, a new relationship bloomed between Picard and

> Laris--who really does look a bit younger--at the end of season 2.

What is the greatest known age separations between Picard and his lovers?

Comment: Does Q count?xD

Comment: No. It wasn't "mutual" :) And the age difference is probably at least few hundred thousand years, which is just absolutely scandalous.

Comment: And he's dating a fully-grown Romulan.

Comment: Perhaps the young wife he had in the episode 'The Inner Light'? This is the episode in which he learns to play the flute.

Comment: Or Marta in  Tapestry.  He was mid sixties, she was early twenties.

Comment: "[Vash](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vash) is one of only two characters with whom Captain Picard had a serious romance during the course of Star Trek: The Next Generation, the other being with Nella Daren." That show doesn't count and neither do any of the movies. And neither do 'the people' in *The Inner Light*.

Comment: "That show doesn't count" - is @Mazura the Pope of Canon?

Comment: Well yeah. If they can't get him to make [a noise like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mpYtyEU8gE4) how am I supposed to take it seriously.

Answer (score 6):

**Picard seems to have a thing for older women.**

In the film *Insurrection*, he has relations with [Anij](https://intl.startrek.com/database_article/anij), a woman who's celebrated her tricentennial. Given that Picard is in his 60s, that would make the age difference between himself and Anij around 240 years.

> They were at her door; as she turned to him to take her leave, he
> said, with feigned seriousness, “There’s one thing I don’t
> understand.” And at her questioning gaze, continued: “In three hundred
> years, you never learned to swim?”
>
> For once, he had her at a disadvantage; she grinned, embarrassed. “I
> just … haven’t gotten around to it yet.”
>
> <sub><sup>Insurrection: Official Novelisation</sup></sub>

---

In the second season of *Star Trek: Picard*, he begins a relationship with his housekeeper [Laris](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Laris). She appears to be in her 50s (the actress that plays her was 59 during filming), although her Romulan physique may mean that she's actually rather older.

Given that

> robo-Picard is only around a year old at this point

the age different would be

> at least 50+ years